# Lost A Company In a Judgement

Tags: united-states, taxes, inheritance, capital-loss

I inherited a company from my father. Not sure what the valuation was. I didn't have any money invested in the company, but the company was sued and we lost it in lieu of not being able to pay the judgment.

If the company was worth say 1,000,000 and I owned 25% of it. Can I continue to write off 250,000 on the capital loss carryover a portion of my taxes? Or do I need to have a cost basis to write it off like this?

Comment: I don’t know the answer to your question, but at the dollar amount level you are talking about, I hope you are seeking advice from an accountant and/or attorney, and not just relying on free advice from the volunteers on our website.

Answer (score 2):

Your cost basis may be the fair market value at the time of your father's death. [Here](https://www.irs.gov/faqs/interest-dividends-other-types-of-income/gifts-inheritances/gifts-inheritances) is the IRS discussion.

Comment: I will look into this and let you know if that's what it's considered. I'm going to attempt to get tax transcripts from the time I took ownership of the estate/company and get an evaluation for my cost basis. I will let you know how it goes, thanks!